# CSS before content vertical align

Tags: html, css

I'm in need of help.
I've search the web for the answer but the answer i found didn't work.

I'm trying to display the content of the a in a box above the a "a:before", and then display the same text as in the a, and i've done that with

```
content:attr(title);
```

But it wont vertical align.
i've tried with

```
display:table-cell;
vertical-align:center;
```

http://jsfiddle.net/CvZkX/

It dosn't work.
Anybody knows how it's done?

Best Regards
Mats

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a single line of text, the easiest solution is to use `line-height`.

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/CvZkX/1/

```css
header nav a:before {
    line-height: 2.3em;
}
```

I chose `2.3em` because you have `.5em` + `.5em` + `1.7em` (`padding-top` + `padding-bottom` + `font-size`), and we're trying to set the `line-height` equal to the height of the element.

Comment: Thank you i tried it with 50% but it didn't work.
I didn't even think about usin em.
Thanks